# How do I suppress this voltage spike/dip?

Tags: capacitor, dc-motor, transient-suppression

I have a system that's currently testing automotive brushed dc motors.  Occasionally, I'm getting interruptions in my data acquisition system that I believe is being caused by transients coming from some of the motors under test.  Below is a transient that I was able to capture (I'm getting positive spikes just as often too).  Could I get rid of this with a bypass capacitor?  If so, based on the graph below and the timing of this transient, how do I size the capacitor?  Is there another device, such as TVS, that would work better?

[image]

UPDATE:

I placed an 18V TVS diode directly across the motor under test, which is roughly 6 meter away from the test system.  The scope measurement below was taken at the test system.  How is this possible?  Shouldn't it be clamped at 18V in the positive direction, and around -0.6V in the negative?

[image]

Comment: Why would a spike like the one shown affect your DAQ system? We only have info from what you present and you haven't said what wire this spike is on or where in the circuit this wire is.

Comment: It is just a theory at the moment.  It's a custom DAQ system and I believe this spike is coupling onto my 3.3V supply, then resetting some ADC's.  The scope trace is the supply voltage to the motors under test.

Comment: No.   If you want to measure AC noise on battery, use either a twin probe balanced differential probe method or better a 50 Ohm terminated AC coupled coax line.  Long inductive leads to a DC couple DAQ with unknown ground reference may give ambiguous false readings.  Unless you  are: e.g.  conducting 100A from a 40 mohm ESR battery to drop 4V

Comment: So start with block diagram of what is significant, measurements and show methods of EMI reduction used already such as STP cables , orientation of cables  etc. BW of signal desired etc

Comment: I'm not trying to measure/log this event.  I want to get rid of it because I believe it is screwing with the functionality of my test system.

Comment: @gtetil - You will only be able to get rid of it once you fully understand what causes it and how it couples around your system. That requires study, measurement and taking notes (logging). There is no magic bullet here.